# How can I pass a string to the Spotify application?

Tags: android, spotify

I want to save a song and artist name in my own android application and pass the string to the spotify android application to play. How can I pass the string to spotify?

Answer (score 0):

If you send the Spotify App a search intent (ie, `spotify:search:whatever`, or `http://open.spotify.com/search/whatever`), you should be able to get the app to play the content.

To search for both artist & track, your URI would look something like this:

```
spotify:search:artist%3Atigerskin%20track%3Astella
```

If you know the specific URI for a track, then you can get spotify to play it directly, which would be much easier than using a search intent.